# BCryptPasswordEncoder - why is it generating too many values?

Tags: java, bcrypt

I have a password update feature that uses the method bellow:

```
protected String encodePassword(String password) {
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    System.out.println(password);
    System.out.println(passwordEncoder.encode(password));

    return passwordEncoder.encode(password);
}
```

That is called in an update method like this:

```
user.setPassword(encodePassword(password));
```

But the console printed output is:

```
abc123
$2a$10$h0ya/4Ly7eenT.I5FAex9OByLa8S8yP.4H1lfGrCq/w4wD93p.4MK
$2a$10$o.//zfHY3jIyuzC0h.Z.c.AL9rPdrrWN4M8DaUpxmtqoQKA0D4udG
$2a$10$arkyirVDsfMbGWhDKBY02ehjDKXXa62yk8fD/b1Pa2I3AhlzhoK.a
$2a$10$5HpCoNtM3mTgBsJlyeP5v.5NdN7YkKkLJMXecJ8fs0yxkB1nrJpiq
$2a$10$94nfxZ7musAu//FRjgxSNOm92vf/FtZU1I2QNPJI3HNVsHfgVnqbi
```

The method is being called only once, but it's generating five different values. How come?

Comment: Are you sure you don't call this in a loop somewhere?  I see three pairs of two which is what I'd expect if this were being invoked three times.

Comment: If it was in a loop, there should be an equal number of the plain text printed out as well, right?

Comment: Repeated invocations will not generate the same hash.

Comment: Yes, I understand that! The problem is that the single execution of this method is spitting out several hash instances...